# Regular Expression with if Condition and if then else condition

Tags: regular-language

How can i solve and use this condition in regular Expression 
if (cond) then s1 else s2.
if (cond1)then if (cond) then s1 else s2. 
please help me

Comment: Do you mean conditional grouping?

Comment: yes @MotKohn exactly

Comment: just use in regular exp

Answer (score 0):

Basically first you give a group a name - for example `(?<grp1>match)`.

Now we have a group named 'grp1', that matched the word 'match'.

Then we can subsequently probe if this group has matched with `(?(R&grp1)yes|no))` which means if grp1 has been matched continue to see if 'yes' now matches otherwise see if 'no' matches.